# Is there an accepted way to remove a tonsilloliths at home?

Tags: dentistry, otolaryngology

Are there any safe, medically accepted ways to remove [tonsilloliths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonsillolith) (tonsil stones) from your mouth at home? Should I instead go to a doctor to get it removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these water injectors on Amazon which squirt a thin stream of water for several dozen seconds and have a curved tip that can reach back into the crevices of tonsils. I was able to remove several of the tonsilliths. The tips are slightly rough but I suppose they can be cut or filed. Shining a flashlight with the other hand lets you see what you are doing. I had hoped for a vacuum solution but this seems to work for less money. Just take a deep breath and hold your breath while doing it.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007Y8230G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007Y8230G)

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to consult a doctor. Tonsilloliths is not a cough or fever that can be remedied only by nutritious intake and rest. It is considered a mucosal infection, thats why, any reckless action may result to further infection and more complication.

Comment: I've already asked a dentist and an ENT to remove them and both refused and told me not to worry about it.

Comment: Then asked them for remedies. It is better for you to ask these things on health care professionals.